# view sql deleted rows log

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I view the log of the deleted rows in a particular table (and actualy see what was deleted)..

Now I'm trying to figure it out `select * from ::fn_dblog(null, null)` but it's just nonsense.

Comment: See http://raresql.com/2011/10/22/how-to-recover-deleted-data-from-sql-sever/ for an example of doing this. What is the motivation for the question?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to recover your data if the database is in full revovery model. You have to perform

1. a transaction log backup
2. restore the most recent full backup with norecovery
3. restore all (if exist) transaction log backups with norecovery
4. restore the last transaction log with recovery using the STOPAT option if you know the exact time that the wrong query has been fired.

If the database is in simple recovery model it is not possible to recover your data.

Comment: I don;t want to recover data .. I just want to see what was deleted ... or fi something was deleted from a table name ..

Comment: Is your system small and with few use?

Comment: No .. it's very big .. and I found some information missing .. so I need to know if in that table were deleted rows ... Thanks

Comment: The info stays in trans log for some time (but not very). So, prolly the info is already gone.